# TinyMCE Shows in Internet Explorer but not in Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce

EDIT: I on a hunch I tried the code below in IE it works fine. It is only Chrome it does not show at all.

I am struggling to get TinyMCE to work in MVC.

The script exists at the location specified (Verified by going to link in browser):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/TinyMCE/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste moxiemanager"
            ],
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
        });
    </script>
```

And this is my textbox:

```
<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" class="tinymce">???</textarea>
</form>
```

If I remove the tincymce.init then the unformatted text box shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like the plugin moxiemanager is not available.
Here is a tinymce fiddle that works for FF and chrome: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/pJdaab/1

Comment: That was the problem I just removed the plug-in
Thanks!